# Why some of the variables are not changed in the nested tag, in RiotJs?

Tags: nested, riot.js

I have a simple nested tag:

```
    <nested-tag>
        <p>myTitle: {myTitle}</p>
        <p>{myKeyword}</p>
        this.myTitle = opts.title;
        this.myKeyword = opts.keyword;
    </nested-tag>
```

You can see I assign the `opts.title` and `keyword` to two new variable `myTitle` and `myKeyword`.

Then I use it in a loop of a parent tag:

```
    <my-tag>
        <input type="text" onkeyup={search} value={keyword} />

        <ul>
           <li each={items}>
           <nested-tag title={title} keyword={parent.keyword}></nested-tag>
           </li>
        </ul>

        this.keyword = ""
        var initItems = [{ title:  "aaaa"}, { title: "bbbb"} ]
        this.items = initItems

        this.search = function(event) {
          this.keyword = event.target.value;
          this.items = initItems.filter((item) => item.title.indexOf(this.keyword) >=0 );
        }
    </my-tag>
```

You can see I passed the `parent.keyword` to `nested-tag` as `keyword` variable.

When I input something to the text input, the `keyword` will be changed, so the `<nested-tag>` will be recreated with the new `parent.keyword`.

But it's not, the `{myKeyword}` of nested-tag is always empty. I have to rewrite it with directly `opts.keyword` invocation:

```
    <nested-tag>
        <p>opts.title</p>
        <p>opts.keyword</p>
    </nested-tag>
```

And it's working well now.

I'm not sure why and how to fix it? Do I have to always use `opts.xxx` in the nested tags?

---

A live demo is here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3jsay5dq/10/

you can type something to the text input to see the result

Answer (score 2):

The javascript in your component `nested-tag` gets run when instantiating the component. So, when the component is getting generated, the `myTitle` and `myKeyword` will be initialized with whatever opts are passed in. But, on update, the `myTitle` and `myKeyword` are still pointing to the values set during instantiation. The cleanest way to go about it is to use `opts[key]` as they will always reflect what is being passed to the component. If you insist on using your own local properties, then you could modify your component like this:

```
<nested-tag>
    <p>myTitle: {myTitle}</p>
    <p>{myKeyword}</p>

    // this will run every time there is an update either internally or from a passed opts
    this.on('update', () => {
        this.myTitle = this.opts.title;
        this.myKeyword = this.opts.keyword;
    })

    // this will only run once during instantiation
    this.myTitle = opts.title;
    this.myKeyword = opts.keyword;

    /* 
    // could be refactored to
    this.setMyProps = () => {
          this.myTitle = this.opts.title;
          this.myKeyword = this.opts.keyword;
    } 

    // bind it to update function
    this.on('update', this.setMyProps)
    // run once for instantiation
    this.setMyProps()

    */
</nested-tag>
```

Comment: ahha! Thank you!